# How to attach TransformControls to own center of mesh group in Three.JS?

Tags: three.js, transform

I attached THREE.TransformControls to mesh and then I added it to scene.

But it's showing in origin position instead center of mesh.

How to make position of TransformControl to center of mesh?

Here is my code snippet I tried.

```
  function createTransformControl(mode) {
    let transform = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, canvas);
    transform.setMode(mode);
    transform.addEventListener('dragging-changed', (event) => {
      cameraCtrl.enabled = !event.value;
    });
    transform.addEventListener('change', () => render());
    return transform;
  }

  function render() {
    scene.updateMatrixWorld();
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  let transformControl = createControl("rotate");
  transformControl.attach(curMesh);
  scene.add(transformControl);
```

In upper code snippet, curMesh is THREE.Group(), scene is THREE.Scene().

Please anyone help.

Comment: Have you considered to transform the origin of the mesh to its center? Depending on the mesh this can be done by calling `mesh.geometry.center()`.

Comment: @Mugen87 Thanks for comment. But I cannot transform mesh, mesh's position is important in my project. Transform control needs to change only rotation of mesh.